# How to access Bing Vision on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: cortana, search, bing-vision

I've been using Windows Phones ever since Windows Phone 8.1, and great features like Cortana were introduced.
To scan `qr codes` in Windows Phones, you need to access the Bing Vision app, which was accessible via the search button. It was never part of the main apps list.
Now that we have Cortana, I can't seem to find and use Bing Vision app anywhere.
I can't seem to find it, even by using Cortana to search for it.

How do i access it..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bing Vision app is obscurely available under the camera app.

First open the Camera application, then click the settings icon, to open this view:

[image]

Click on the Lenses option, and...voila

[image: Bing Vision]

Bing Vision will be available, amongst all the other lenses and camera related applications, as shown above.